# Passing data to another page after form submit with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, post

I've read through a number of similar questions, so I know this has been answered before, but now my question is why isn't what I'm doing working?

I'm new to web development, developing a web form that passes the submitted data to a CSV file. What I currently do, is after all form validation is done on the form page "form.php", it sends the user to another page "submittedApplication.php", and in the same statement goes all of my code to push the data into a CSV.

What I NEED, is to pass one particular variable from "form.php", over to "submittedApplication.php". It's a reference number that I have a random generator for, on form.php.

In my code I use a function to create the reference number, I store it in a variable called $result. In the bottom of the validation I use

```
header('Location: submittedApplication.php?result={$result}');
```

to try and pass it over, and then in the second page I use

```
echo $_GET['result'];
```

to try and grab the variable.

If you spot it in my code, I've also tried the hidden input method, to no avail as well.

**Here is my form.php main page**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <?php
    //Define variables and set to empty values

    //###CUSTOMER DATA###
    //Name
    $custName= "";
    $custNameError = "";

    //Reference Number

    $result = gen_uid();

    //Error holders
    $errors = ""; //Generic Error list at top of form, can be appended to
    $error = 0;   //Error Tally, If 0 = good. If 1 = error.


    //Generates a 10 character random string with a prefix and current date attached 
    function gen_uid($l=10){ 
        $prefix = "BLANK DATA#";
        $str = ""; 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $date = date("Y.m.d");

        for ($x=0;$x<$l;$x++)
        $str .= substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 1);
        echo $prefix . $str . "<br/>" . "Generated On: " . $date; }

    //for testing
    echo $result;


    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET"){
        $custName = "";
        $custAddress = "";
    }
    else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { // Checking null values in message.

     $custName = $_POST['customername'];
     $custAddress = $_POST['CustomerMailingAddress'];

     $passedResult = $_POST['result'];


    //################################## Form Validation #####################################
        //CUSTOMER NAME
        if(!isset($custName) || $custName == "")
        {

            $custNameError = "Name required";
            $errors .= "Customer contact information required, Contractor optional.<br/>";
            $custName = "";
            $error = 1;
        }
        else{
            $custName = $_POST['customername'];
        }

        if($error == 0) 
        {
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='result' value='{$result}'/>";

             //this is where the creating of the csv takes place
             $cvsData = $custName . "," . $custAddress . "," . $custPhone . "," . $custMobile . "," . $custFax . "," . $custEmail . "," . $conName . "," . $conAddress . "," .
             $custPhone . "," . $conPhone . "," . $custMobile . "," . $conMobile . "," . $custEmail . "," . $conEmail . "," . $accNum ."\n";

             $fp = fopen("formTest.csv","a"); // $fp is now the file pointer to file $filename

             if($fp){
             fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file
             fclose($fp); // Close the file
             }
        header('Location: submittedApplication.php?result={$result}');
        }
    }
    ?>

        <body>
            <h2 align="center"><u>Service Request Application Form</u></h2>
            <hr>

            <h4>NOTES:</h4>

            <div id="wrapper">
    <br/>
    <h3 class="error"><?php echo $errors; ?></h3>
            <form method="post" align="center" name="applicationform" id="applicationform" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <!--###################################### CONTACT INFORMATION FIELDSET ######################################-->
                <fieldset  style="border: 1px black solid" align="center">
                    <legend style="font-weight:bold"><u>Contact Information</u></legend>
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th><u>Customer</u></th>
                    <th title="Electrician"><u>Consultant/Contractor</u></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right" id="namelabel">Contact Name:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="customername" name="customername" value="<?php echo $custName;?>" title="Name of contact on account"/></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="contractorname" name="contractorname" title="Name of contractor or consultant" /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><div class="error"><?php echo $custNameError;?></div></td>
                            <td></td>
                            </tr>




                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    </table>            
                </table>
            </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**And here is my second page submittedApplication.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>          
            <h2 align="center"><u>Service Request Application Form</u></h2>
            <hr>

            <h4>NOTES:</h4>
                <hr>

        <div align="center"><h3>Application Submitted Successfully!</h3> </div>

        <?php
                echo $_GET['result'];
        ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Any and all tips are appreciated!**

Comment: Why is this so long? D:

Comment: @JustCarty How would you have done it differently?

Comment: There's too much code here. Find the relevant parts and post that.

Comment: I didnt read all of your code, but the { } in this line is unnecesary `header('Location: submittedApplication.php?result={$result}');`. It should be `header('Location: submittedApplication.php?result=' . $result . ');`

Comment: @Qirel I've pulled out about 80% of the code that was there previously, I've left only the basic shell of the form, only a couple declarations, but kept the part with my random ID generator and the validation that submits it all if correct.

Comment: For one, as pointed out already, `?result={$result}');` in the `header()` call will literally be `{$result}`, because its inside single-quotes and not double quotes. Either wrap the entire string in double-quotes, or concat it, as `?result='.$result);`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that Qirel, the first explanation had incorrect apostrophes that confused me on how it was supposed to be changed.

Comment: @Qirel  I might post a new question, because I realized I've got it working except for the fact that it wont post my data that I get from my function. I send it across using the header location you just fixed for me. On my second page I grab it using GET. But it only works when I have text literal in my variable from the first page. MEANING: $result = gen_uid(); (this calls my function that generates the unique ID) DOES NOT WORK. What does work, is: $result = "TEST"; ... The "test" comes through on the second page, but if I use the function call it does not. And it's random so I cant duplicate

Answer (score 0):

The way I would normally tackle passing values between pages is to use session variables.

You can do this in your form.php page

`session_start();
 $SESSION_["result"] = $result;`

Then do the following in your other page

```
session_start();
if(isset($SESSION_["result"]) {
    $result = $SESSION_["result"];
}
```

Just make sure you destroy or unset any session variables when you're done with them.