# Passing Data taken from function call to second PHP Page

Tags: php, html, forms

As a result of discussion on my previous question:

[Passing data to another page after form submit with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662986/passing-data-to-another-page-after-form-submit-with-php)

I've discovered my syntax is correct but not working the way I need it.

I'm trying to pass a variable from my first page (my page with a form) to my second page (basically just a splash to say they submitted the form).

The variable is a unique ID used as a reference number for the submission. I get the unique ID by generating a random sequence in a function.

My problem is such: I can get my variable to pass across the two pages with this code

```
//(First Page)
$result = "TEST";
header('Location: submittedApplication.php?result='. $result);
```

and I grab it with this code

```
//(Second Page)
echo $_GET['result'];
```

Which works and passes a variable for me. But what I need is to utilize this function:

```
    function gen_uid($l=10)
        { 
        $prefix = "#####";
        $str = ""; 
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
        $date = date("Y.m.d");

        for ($x=0;$x<$l;$x++)
        $str .= substr(str_shuffle("0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 1);
        echo $prefix . $str . "<br/>" . "Generated On: " . $date; 
        }
```

What I would like to use is

```
$result = gen_uid();
```

But it just passes empty to the second page, even though when I echo it out to test on the first page it works and gives me data like this

```
######NMB32R3MVQ
Generated On: 2017.04.27
```

As a recap; Page 1 is: **form.php**, Page 2 is: **submittedApplication.php**, I'm trying to pass **$result** (while holding the string my function generates) from page 1 -> page 2. I'm new to web development so I'm open to any avenue of getting this to work, I'm just not able to determine what avenue that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is giving a null value because you're not returning anything from the function `gen_uid()`, you're only echoing things.

Comment: Its times like these that I question my sanity. I needed that second set of eyes, has anyone told you they love you recently? Cause I love you.

Comment: @AdamLee Whenever you get a null value from a function, no return value is usually the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Function you have created is not returning the desired result its just displaying it.
Replace:

`echo $prefix . $str . "<br/>" . "Generated On: " . $date;`

with

```
$final_result = $prefix . $str . "<br/>" . "Generated On: " . $date;
return $final_result;
```

this should resolve your problem.